# ode solver event location index in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, solver, differential-equations

Suppose I am trying to solve a system of differential equations using an `ode` solver in MATLAB.

Suppose also that I have defined an events functions to locate three different events which are all terminal.

I have noticed that on some occasions the `ie` quantity that is returned upon the location of one of the events (`ie` is the index of the event that stopped the solver, in my case it could be 1, 2 or 3) is not always a single number but a vector with two elements (usually these elements are identical)

In those cases that `ie` is NOT scalar, is it `ie(1)` or `ie(2)` that stopped the solver?

Comment: Is a simple example available? Are multiple events satisfied at the end?

Comment: I've added an example in the question post. Also note that in my experience it is `ie(2)` that normally contains the event that stopped the ode and `ie(1)` is just a repetation of the previous time that the solver stopped. But this is just my experience, it's not to be taken for granted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I noticed that this happens when the simulation stops due to a terminal event and then starts again from the same point (initial time and conditions) that stopped.

Technically, due to arithmetic inaccuracies in the initial conditions MATLAB re-detects the same event that made it previously stop. MATLAB is incapable of distinguishing this, BUT it is programmed NOT to stop in terminal events that occur just after the **first** successful step (see `odezero` function for reference). It does record the event, though.

Consequently, the next time that the ode stops due to a terminal event, the `ie` is *appended* with the new index and that's when (and why) `ie` is a vector with two elements.